# Display 'Related Item' Field in a Task 'Edit' Form

Tags: workflow, javascript, form, task-list

Is there any way to display 'Related Items' in a task edit form?  It's already available in the display form, but when you switch to edit, it drops off.  Ideas?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I am searching for the same feature.

Comment: Nope.  Nothing yet.  I had to go back to using the display form in the meantime.  I'm sure there must be a way to do it...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This worked for me...thanks to BlumShapiro.

http://blog.blumshapiro.com/blog/2014/03/14/customize-related-items-field-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: URL is broken, please provide summary of the solution